# How to use Sympys NumPyPrinter?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am trying to print my Sympy-expression as a string ready to be used with Numpy. I just cannot figure out how to do it.

I found that there is sp.printing.pycode: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/printing/pycode.html

The web page states that "This module contains python code printers for plain python as well as NumPy & SciPy enabled code.", but I just cannot figure out how to get it to output the expression numpy format.

```
sp.printing.pycode(expr)
'math.cos((1/2)*alpha)*math.cos((1/2)*beta)'
```

That web page also contain `class NumPyPrinter(PythonCodePrinter)` but I do not know how to use it. `def pycode(expr, **settings)` just seems to use `return PythonCodePrinter(settings).doprint(expr)` as a default all the time.

Comment: Have you tried to do `NumPyPrinter().doprint(expr)`?

Comment: How do you call it? `sp.printing.NumPyPrinter().doprint(x)` results in `module 'sympy.printing' has no attribute 'NumPyPrinter'` and `sp.printing.pycode.NumPyPrinter().doprint(x)` results in `'function' object has no attribute 'NumPyPrinter'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `pycode` is almost trivial:

```
def pycode(expr, **settings):
    # docstring skipped
    return PythonCodePrinter(settings).doprint(expr)
```

It should be straight forward to run `NumPyPrinter().doprint(expr)` instead. The problem is that `sympy.printing` re-exports the `pycode` function which shadows the module with the same name. However, we can still import the class directly and use it:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.printing.pycode import NumPyPrinter

x = sy.Symbol('x')
y = x * sy.cos(x * sy.pi)

code = NumPyPrinter().doprint(y)

print(code)
# x*numpy.cos(numpy.pi*x)
```

Comment: It is this shadowing thing that prevents this syntax from working? `sympy.printing.pycode.NumPyPrinter().doprint(expr)`

Comment: Yes. It's the line `from .pycode import pycode` in [`printing/__init__.py`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/printing/__init__.py#L17). When you yo use `scipy.printing.pycode` you use the `pycode` function instead of the `pycode` module. I do not know why the sympy folks decided to have it that way.